# UploadPhotoActivity not found on android's facebook app

Tags: android, facebook

Since december 15, when the new app for facebook was launched i started to get this error:

E/AndroidRuntime(10977): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.katana.UploadPhotoActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Somebody knows the whereabouts of this activity? This activity is in fact in the debuggable apk of the facebook-sdk, but not in the real one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVM the new activity is called ComposerActivity, if someone needs that info. BTW looks like you cant add a preset text, due to facebook politics, ofc if someone knows how to do that, let me know.